# Асинхронное программирование await async

Tags: c#, асинхронность, async-await

[image]Всем привет!

Пытаюсь разобраться с асинхронным вызовом методов. Узнал такую вещь: если предполагается, что некоторый метод может долго выполнятся, то его можно перенести в "фоновое" выполнение, а управление отдать в вызывающий метод. Решил разобраться с этим и написал для начала обычный код без асинхронного программирования.

```
class Test
{
    public  static void Download()
    {        
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(@"http://www.ukraine.com.ua/static/100MB.bin");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
        Console.WriteLine("Hell");
        Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Download();
    }
}
```

Здесь вроде все понятно, пока загружается 100мб файл, соответственно остальные инструкции в методе Download() не выполняются до окончания загрузки. То есть идет последовательное выполнение. Далее я решил поэкспериментировать с await и async и написал следующий код:

```
class Test
{
    public async  static void Download()
    {        
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] data = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(@"http://www.ukraine.com.ua/static/100MB.bin");        
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
        Console.WriteLine("Hell");
        Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Download();
    }
}
```

Как видно, логика кода такая же, только добавлены await и async и под них изменен метод на DownloadDataTaskAsync.

В этом коде я ожидал такое поведение:

1. Файл начинает скачиваться.
2. Так как закачка переходит в фоновый режим, то управление возвращается методу Download(), и следовательно выводится на консоль Welcome to Hell.
3. По окончании загрузки файла выводится результат Lengеth.

Однако всего этого не происходит, а вместо этого просто запускается консоль без единого сообщения, кроме того, чтобы я нажал эникей. Почему так происходит, или где я ошибся в коде?

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну а чего вы хотели-то? Чтобы у вас часть метода выполнялась асинхронно, а другая часть синхронно? Так не бывает. Вы же сами пишете в методе **await**, что заставляет дождаться выполнения загрузки.

Comment: Про эникей сами разбирайтесь, а await тормозит последующее выполнение строк и включается после выполнения метода. То есть для наглядности в методе Main нужно после Download выводить Welcome to hell.

Comment: Что-то совсем тяжко )) Не могу понять...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Управление методу Download тоже передается, просто вы его сразу же возвращаете. Если хочется параллельности - надо разнести по времени запуск задачи и ее ожидание. Надо понимать, что асинхронные методы всего лишь возвращают объект `Task` (или `Task<>`) - который всегда можно сохранить в переменную.

Вот вам такой пример:

```
class Test
{
    public static async Task Download()
    {        
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var task = wc.DownloadData(@"http://www.ukraine.com.ua/static/100MB.bin");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
        Console.WriteLine("Hell");
        Console.WriteLine((await task).Length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Download().Wait();
    }
}
```

Это то, чего вы пытались добиться?

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так оно должно быть.

```
internal class Program {
        public static async Task<byte[]> Download() {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            byte[] data = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(@"https://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2015/emmy-noethers-133rd-birthday-5681045017985024-hp.jpg");
            return data;
        }

        private static async void ProcessDataAsync() {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin download...");
            var task = Download();
            var result = await task;
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes downloaded: " + result.Length);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            Task task = new Task(ProcessDataAsync);
            task.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
            Console.WriteLine("Hell");

            task.Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Или можно вот так:

```
internal class Program {
    public static async Task<byte[]> Download() {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] data = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(@"https://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2015/emmy-noethers-133rd-birthday-5681045017985024-hp.jpg");
        return data;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var task = Download();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
        Console.WriteLine("Hell");

        Task.WaitAll(task);
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes downloaded: " + task.Result.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваш пример первый прекрасно работает. Хотя в чем его хитрость не могу понять. Я только что воспроизвел полностью ваш первый пример путем использования обычной многопоточности через класс Thread. И все получилось то же самое. Зачем тогда нужны await и async ?? Меня очень с толку сбила книга насчет использования этих ключевых слов. Скрин прикрепил к теме.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. На него уже есть ответ на stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148852/async-await-vs-threads :)

Comment: Async/Await, более новая и, как мне кажется, более простая методика создания многопоточных приложений. Часто и густо это стали использовать в вэбе. Но как я понял, возможности у Threads шире. Просто они в большинстве случаев не нужны программисту.

Comment: Я не перепроверил, но нме кажется, что у вас не получалось как в книге ибо метод у вас void, а в книге есть return-value. Они, вроде как, чуток по разному работают.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался! Моя ошибка была в том, что я предполагал, будто управление при вызове метода DownloadDataTaskAsync передается методу Download (в чем меня сбил скриншот из книги). После нехитрых манипуляций с кодом, понял, что управление передается методу, который вызывает Download, т.е. методу Main().

```
class Test
{
    public async static void Download()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] data = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(@"http://www.ukraine.com.ua/static/100MB.bin");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
        Console.WriteLine("Hell");
        Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Download();
        Thread.Sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> В этом коде я ожидал такое поведение

Для того, чтобы его получить, надо сделать так:

```
class Test
{
    public async  static void Download()
    {        
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var task = wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(@"http://www.ukraine.com.ua/static/100MB.bin");        
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to");
        Console.WriteLine("Hell");
        byte[] data = await task;
        Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Download();
    }
}
```

Comment: Любители ставить минусы - поясните, что не так в ответе.